# querying on 10 million mongodb documents

Tags: php, mongodb

I am storing book meta-data like name,authors,price,publisher,etc in a mongodb document. I have about 10 million of these documents and they all are in one collection. *The average document size is 1.9 KB*. Now i have indexes on `name`,`authors` and `price`. In fact *i have 2 indexes on price one in ascending order and one descending order*. My mongodb version is 2.2.0 and i am using the php driver to query mongo. The driver's version is 1.12. But when i do a range query on price i get a `MongoCursorTimeoutException`. In my query i am trying to find books in a certain price range like "price less than 1000 and more than 500".

Increasing the timeout doesn't seem to be a good idea(It is already 30 sec). Is there anything else that i can do to speed up the query process.

**EDIT**
Actually my price index is compound. I have a status field which has an integer value so my price index looks like `{price:-1,status:1}` and `{price:1,status:1}`
Also I am trying to retrieve 20 documents at a time with PHP.

Comment: memcached? that's 18 gigs, no wonder. how much memory do you have installed?

Comment: @iccthedral i have 8 GB ram. But my total index size is about 6 GB. So i have enough memory to keep my indexes in RAM

Comment: Having separate ascending and descending indexes on price is a waste.  Direction [doesn't matter](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeys) for single-field indexes.  Remove one of them to free up some index RAM.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Actually my price index is compound. I have a status field which has an integer value so my price index look like `{price:-1,status:1}` and `{price:1,status:1}`

Comment: @lovesh OK; even then, be sure to use `explain` to make sure both of those index are being used.  Regardless, having 6GB of indexes and 8GB of RAM feels too tight.

Comment: I did an explain and it shows only one index is being used. I should drop the other index

Comment: @JohnnyHK `explain` shows `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor price_-1_status_1"` which means that that the compound index is being used but the "isMultiKey" value is false. Can you tell why?

Comment: @lovesh `isMultiKey` is an indication of whether the index was for an array property so it makes sense to be false here.  Any given query can only use one index so I didn't mean to imply you should check that they're both used in this specific query.  Rather I meant to check in any of your queries where you're expecting the index to help.

Comment: @JohnnyHK So would upgrading to 10 GB be OK?

Comment: @lovesh It would certainly be OK, hard to know if it will be enough until you try it and analyze the results.

Comment: How many different values do you have for "status"? 10Gen warns not to throw an index on a field that has only a few possible values (e.g., a field for "gender" would be a poor candidate for an index).

Comment: @SethO `status` can have values from 0 to 3

Comment: @lovesh why wasn't my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JohnyHK said my RAM was too low. So increased it to 12 GB and it works now. Thanks everyone for their comments and answers

Answer (score 5):

We have had a lot of experience with Mongo collections with millions of documents using both single/shared servers and dedicated replica sets on EC2 using both traditional and SSD EBS volumes. The workloads are varied: some are analytics-oriented and others are backing Web requests. Here is the root cause analysis path I'd recommend:

1. Run your queries with [`.explain()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) to see what's going on in terms of indexes used, etc. Adjust indexes if necessary. Mongo's optimizer is rather naive so if your indexes don't match the query pattern perfectly, they may be missed.
2. Check [MMS](http://mms.10gen.com/) and look for any of the following problems: (1) not all data in memory (indicated by page faults) and (2) queue lengths (typically indicating some type of bottleneck). Mongo's performance degrades rapidly when not all data is in memory because the database has a single global lock and touching storage, especially in the cloud is bad news. We recently upgraded to SSD cloud storage and we are seeing 3-10x improvements in performance on a database that's about 1/2 Tb in size.
3. Increase the profiling level to 2 (the max), run for a while and look at the operation log. See the [MongoDB profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your indecies. Reindex your data, and make sure that the collection is fully indexed before running the queries. (10 mi. docs may take awhile to index)
2. The slowest part of any indexed query is the actual document retrieval. I could imagine that depending on the amount of documents you are pulling this could take 30 seconds or more and a lot of memory.

For more helpful instructions on some things you could try check out this page:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization

For 10 mi. documents you might also think about sharding the data across computers. Remember that hard drive reads are slower than cpu cycles.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve 20 documents at a time so `limit` is 20